# Initializing an array on arbitrary starting index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to initialize an array in, for example, subindex 1?

```
GenderArray: ['Female', 'Male', 'Other'],
```

I want the Female to be `1`, Male to be `2` and Other to be `3`.

Comment: You can use the json instead of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put in a dummy:

```
GenderArray: [undefined, 'Female', 'Male', 'Other'],
```

If you need an arbitrary position in the array use `splice()` as in:

```
GenderArray = [];
GenderArray.splice(4, 3, 'Female', 'Male', 'Other');
```

Which will put them in starting at position 4.

Comment: no guarantee undefined is really undefined . For example I can assign undefined a value .

Comment: @dan_l So don't :) Simple. And he's ignoring that one anyway. Edit: No you can't. I just tried assigning a value to undefined and it ignored it.

Comment: It works on Chrome .  undefined = 999; if (undefined) { console.log("yes"); }

Comment: @dan_l Sounds like a bug to me, you should report it. And it did not work in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

It's not possible or at least not in all browsers. For example if you do something like this:

```
var a = [];

a[1] = "Female";
a[2] = "Male";
a[3] = "Other";
```

And later access a[0] it will return ***undefined***. When you are initializing array JS engine allocates memory for let's say 20 elements which are indexed from 0.

You can ignore element at 0th index and use your array but please note that in your loops you need to specify starting index as 1 like:

```
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) { ... }
```

And also be aware that your array's length will be 4 not 3 as you might expect in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON. I think json is the best way for using associative arrays:

```
var myjsonobject = { 1: "Female", 2:"Male",3:"Other"}
```

Then Call it like this :

```
 alert(myjsonobject[1]) //for female
 alert(myjsonobject[2]) //for male
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are pretty confused. You just created an object, not an array, and it has nothing to do with JSON - that's javascript syntax.

Comment: I think JSON full form is JavaScript Obect Notation :)